# Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS sound lag using wireless earbuds watching video like Netflix

Tags: sound, firefox, video

Have Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS on Ideapad 330 IGM 14. Using wireless earbuds from Verveones+ ME works great except when watching Netflix which goes with annoying lag in sound. Motorola says it is due to Firefox or OS settings. Appreciate ideas / suggestions

Comment: Does the issue only happen with Netflix?  You should do some process of elimination by testing sound in other applications or on other websites, like VLC and Youtube, then report back here.  I know of nothing in Firefox or Ubuntu that would cause a delay in audio.  Can you elaborate on what motorola says could be causing the issue?  While it's unlikely for software to cause a delay, It is very common, however, for audio delays caused connection between your client and the server (Netflix), or even more likely, issues with electromagnetic interference that can happen with wireless devices.

Comment: Thanks Nmath! Affirmative; this happens with Netflix. Other streams are OK. Motorola says it is not them but settings Firefox or Ubuntu. I have looked everywhere for settings on Firefox or Ubuntu. Find nothing. So when watching Netflix I use wired ear buds. Enjoy your weekend. Cheers